# Cannot access empty property in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i cannot get the post value from the form it inserting empty values in database

user controller

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
    if ($id) {
        $this->data ['user'] = $this->user_login_model->get($id);
        count ( $this->data ['user'] ) or $this->data ['errors'] [] = "user could not be found";
    } else {
        $this->data ['user'] = $this->user_login_model->new_user ();
    }

    $rules = $this->user_login_model->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules ['password'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( $rules );
    if ($this->form_validation->run () == TRUE) {

          $data=$this->user_login_model->array_from_post(array('name','email','password'));
        $this->data['password']=$this->user_login_model->$data['password'];
        $this->user_login_model->save($data,$id);
        redirect('admin/users');

        // do stuff

    }
```

if it's a new user then it will post new data

```
public function new_user() {
    $user=new stdClass();
    $user->name ='';
    $user->email ='';
    $user->password ='';
    return $user;

    var_dump($user);
```

model  method  which will loop through the array and return it

```
public function array_from_post($fields) {
    $data = array ();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        $data['feild']=$this->input->post($field);
        return $data;
    echo var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

this is the var_dump

```
object(stdClass)[22]
public 'id' => string '18' (length=2)
public 'email' => string '' (length=0)
public 'password' => string '' (length=0)
public 'name' => string '12' (length=2)
```

this is empty  , can you tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: I guess your this line is wrong `$data['feild']=$this->input->post($field);` This should be $data[$feild]=$this->input->post($field);

Comment: i tried both not working

Comment: did you tried with `$data[$field]=$this->input->post($field);` besides of `$data[$feild]=$this->input->post($field);`?

Comment: When you say the var_dump is empty, which one do you mean? The one is new_user() or the one is array_from_post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Your controller edit function

```
  public function edit($id = NULL) {
    if ($id)
    {
        $this->data ['user'] = $this->user_login_model->get($id);
        count ( $this->data ['user'] ) or $this->data ['errors'] [] = "user could not be found";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data ['user'] = $this->user_login_model->new_user ();
    }

    $rules = $this->user_login_model->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules ['password'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( $rules );
    if ($this->form_validation->run () == TRUE)
    {

        $this->data=$this->user_login_model->array_from_post(array('name','email','password'));
        $this->data=$this->array_from_post(array('name','email','password'));

        // I removed this line not sure what you did here
        $this->user_login_model->save($this->data,$id);
        // do stuff
        redirect('admin/users');

    }
}
```

Your model array_from_post function

```
public function array_from_post($fields)
{
    $data = array ();
    foreach ( $fields as $field )
    {
        $data[$field]=$this->input->post($field);

    }
    return $data;

}
```

Your new user function

```
 public function new_user() {
    $user=new stdClass();
    $user->name ='';
    $user->email ='';
    $user->password ='';
    return $user;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: ITS SAYIING CANNOT ACESS EMPTY PROPERTY , AND UNDEFINED INDEX PASSWORD  ?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: password

Filename: admin/users.php

Line Number: 25

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in E:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\system\core\Model.php on line 51
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 389920 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.0031 462992 require_once( 'E:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' ) ..\index.php:202
3 0.1686 3912800 call_user_func_array ( ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
4 0.1686 3912848 Users->edit( ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:0
5 0.1791 3953936 CI_Model->__get( ) ..\Model.php:0

Answer (score 0):

Your array_from_post function is basically useless. You have a `return` INSIDE the loop, meaning you abort the loop/return from the function the FIRST time you try to iterate the loop. So you'll only ever return **ONE** of your argument values.

e.g.

```
array_from_post(array('foo', 'bar'));

foreach(array('foo', 'bar') as $field) {
   return $field;
}
```

You start the loop, `foo` gets assigned to $field, and then you return. The loop will NEVER reach `bar`.

You probably want

```
public function array_from_post($fields) {
    $data = array ();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        $data[$field]=$this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Note `$data[$field]`. Using `$data['feild']` will simply give you an array with ONE value in it, the last one which got processed by the loop. And note how the return call is OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: i have tried using $data[$field] but still the problem occur

Comment: done any basic debugging, like look at the source of your generated html page and seeing if the field names are what you expect them to be? `var_dump($_POST)` to see what php is receiving, blah blah blah?

Comment: object(stdClass)[22]
  public 'id' => string '18' (length=2)
  public 'email' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'name' => string '12' (length=2)

Comment: i am getting empty email and password